# How can I filter a loop and "save for later" the result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the amazon website for a project I'm working on.

Until now I've built this flow

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.get('hhttps://www.amazon.it/s?k=shoes&__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3B00FY4A5NJBZ&sprefix=shoes'
       '%2Caps%2C122&ref=nb_sb_noss')

products = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "sg-col-4-of-12 s-result-item s-asin sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col '
                                              's-widget-spacing-small sg-col-4-of-20"]')

for product in products:
    name = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]').text
    brand = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-size-base-plus a-color-base"]').text
    price = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-price-whole"]').text
```

After generating this flow I want to filter the results by price (for example I want to maintain everything below 100€) and "save" the outputon a list/group to concatenate it with another loop results

Thanks
Car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a `dict` for every product to a `list` would be one approache to hold your data for post processing:

```
data = []

for product in products:

    data.append({
        'name':product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]').text,
        'brand':product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-size-base-plus a-color-base"]').text,
        'price':product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class = "a-price-whole"]').text
    })
```

You can use this list of dicts to simply create a `DataFrame` for filtering and [saving](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data) #create dataframe
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float) #convert strings to float
df[df['price'] < 100].to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False) #filter dataframe and save to excel
```

#### Output

|  | name | brand | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Graceful-Get Connected, Sneaker Donna | Skechers | 40 |
| 1 | Court Royale 2, Scarpe Uomo | Nike | 54.99 |
| 2 | Og 85 Gold'n Gurl, Scarpe da Ginnastica Donna | Skechers | 54.93 |
| 3 | Smash, Scarpe da Ginnastica. Uomo | PUMA | 28.43 |
| 4 | Wearallday, Scarpe da corsa Donna, NULL, NULL | Nike | 55.48 |
| 5 | Uomo Claudio A, Scarpe Stringate Basse Derby | Geox | 46.16 |
| 6 | Court Graffik, Scarpa da Skate Bambini e Ragazzi | DC Shoes | 19.92 |
| 7 | Hiking, Kids Shedir Mid Highing Shoes WP-Scarpe da Ginnastica Unisex-Bambini e Ragazzi | CMP | 33.68 |
| 8 | Court Graffik, Scarpe da Ginnastica Basse Uomo | DC Shoes | 50.98 |
| ... |  |  |  |

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. About the data filter, once identified all the elements in the webpage, I would like to filter out all the elements name + brand + price if the price is higher or equal to 100. For example in the page I scrape Nike - Metcon - 113 & Adidas - Low quality -30, here I wanto to maintain only the second element

Comment: the filter is in this line `df[df['price'] < 100]` - I had revised the answer in the meantime, so it may have overlapped with your comment.